# Get users position between friends

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a users position between the users friends, but I don't have any idea of how I can do this...

I have two tables.

Table 1: friends (where all the users friends are listed)

Table 2: users (where all the users are listed)

I want the query to check the users position between his friends.

So if I, for example have ID 1 (with 100 credits) and a friend with ID 2 (with 21 credits), the query would list my position as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really provide much information on your table layout, so it's going to be impossible for me to provide a very specific example. I'm also afraid I don't really understand your question, but I'll give it a shot...

First, I'll assume your **users** table has at least these columns:

```
id (PK)
credits
```

And that the **friends** table has these columns:

```
user (FK to users.id)
friend (FK to users.id)
```

Now, if I understand your question, you want to rank all of a user's friends, based on how many credits they have, so:

```
SELECT u.id,u.credits
FROM friends AS f
JOIN users AS us ON f.friend = u.id
WHERE f.user = 1
ORDER BY u.credits DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the position I would recommend using PHP for this and not try to put it all in one query. So get a sorted list like Flimzy described and get the position by using an array function like array_search.